# Inserting values from input text field

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'd like to insert input value from my simple form into DB. When I pass Key to the function, I still always insert those Keys. Probably problem with syntax, but didn't find solution yet.

```
    col2 = [[sg.Text('Description')],[sg.InputText(key='-DESC-')],[sg.Text('KCal')],[sg.InputText(key='-KCal-')]]
    layout = [[sg.Column(col2)], [sg.Button(button_text='Insert', key='-INSERT-')], [sg.Button(button_text='Back', key='-BACK-')]]
    return sg.Window("Records", layout, size = (900,300), finalize=True)
```

```
 elif event == '-INSERT-':
        insert.insert_record_Food('-DESC-','-KCal-')
```

**insert_record_Food function:**

```
def insert_record_Food (Description, KCal):

    myDb = con.connect()
    myCursor = myDb.cursor()
    myCursor.execute("INSERT INTO Food (Description, KCal) VALUES (?, ?)", (Description, KCal))
    myDb.commit()
    myDb.close()
    print(myCursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

I always get into DB is -DESC- and -KCal-

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you need to share more of the surrounding code in those first two blocks to help find the correct answer, but the primary issue is that in the 2nd block with `insert.insert_record_Food('-DESC-','-KCal-')`, you are passing the literal strings '-DESC-' and '-KCal-' to insert_record_food(Description, KCal), where you meant to pass the values currently entered in the form by the user corresponding to those keys.

Comment: `insert.insert_record_Food(values['-DESC-, values['-KCal-'])`